# Size(height/width) is showing differently than given in CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a sample tables,inputs and containers with (pure) HTML and CSS. The height is showing other than what i'm giving in the CSS. For example, Given height is 44px but in browser it is showing as 73px.

Why this is happening?

Is there any fault in my code?

[image: Sample image]

My sample code is given in code pen and below:
https://codepen.io/ramlals/pen/vwEYbo

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Table template</title>
    <style>
       .table-column {
            min-height: 1px;
            padding-left: 15px;
            padding-right: 15px;
        }

        .table-panel {
            background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
            border: none;
            border-radius: 5px;
            margin-bottom: 15px;
            box-shadow: 0 5px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
            color: #fff;
        }
        .table-panel-heading{
            padding: 14px 22px;
            height: 44px;
            border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.12);
            box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 rgba(255,255,255,.12);

        }
        .table-panel-title{
            font-weight: 400px;
            opacity: .9;
            text-transform: uppercase;
        }

    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="table-container table-column">
        <div class="table-panel">
            <div class="table-panel-heading">
                <h3 class="table-panel-title">Status</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="table-panel-body">
                <table class="table-tag">
                    <tr>
                        <th>col-1</th>
                        <th>col-2</th>
                        <th>col-3</th>
                        <th>col-4</th>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td>chrome1</td>
                        <td>chrome 2</td>
                        <td>chrome 3</td>
                        <td>chrome 4</td>
                    </tr>

                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone posted the answer and removed, before I accept it.

This Works for my code:

Just adding the following in my CSS-

```
* {
         box-sizing: border-box;
         margin: 0;
         padding: 0;
       }
```

Answer (score 4):

What you see is the "total" height. i.e. The `height` + top and bottom `padding` and the `border-bottom`. (44 + 28 + 1 = 73)

Answer (score 3):

Add 
box-sizing: border-box;

```
 .table-panel-heading{
            padding: 14px 22px;
            height: 44px;
            border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.12);
            box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 rgba(255,255,255,.12);
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }
```

Comment: You should add a few explanation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing and also tell about table behavior , sizing to fit its content

Answer (score 1):

I think either you have not given `box-sizing` or it's given as `content-box` so this is happening because of that. Change it to `border-box`.

For `content-box` `height` and `width` include `padding` and `border` as well. In your case it's `height` as **44px** and `padding-top` and `padding-bottom` is **14px** and a `border-bottom` of **1px** is there. So, in total it's **44 + 14 + 14 + 1 = 73px**.